# jQuery validation error message inside input field disappears at focus

Tags: jquery, validation

I have jQuery validation error message show up in the input fields of each required fields.  I can't figure out how to make the message go away when user tries to input valid required information.

For example, if error message occurs in input field as "Enter your first name", and I try to type my real first name (if it was Steve) in the text input field it starts from "Enter your Steve"

How can I have the error message go away as I typed in the real info?

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antwonlee/3RBRp/)

Here are my codes:

**HTML**

```
<form id="lead">
<input type="text" name="first_name">
<input type="text" name="last_name">
<input type="email" name="email">
<input type="submit">
```

**jQuery**

```
    $(function () {
    //Validation
    $('#lead').validate({
        rules: {
            first_name: {
                minlength: 2,
                required: true
            },
            last_name: {
                minlength: 2,
                required: true
            },
            email: {
                email: true,
                required: true
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            element.val(error.text());
        },
        messages: {
            first_name: "Enter your first name",
            last_name: "Enter your last name",
            email: "Enter your email"
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can get the behaviour you want with these exact settings in jQuery Validate.

The problem is that you've set `minlength: 2` for your name input.  Before you submit the form, Validate does nothing.  But after the first submit, and errors have been triggered, it reevaluates the validation criteria on **every** keystroke.  So you type "S" into the first name input, and that triggers a validation, which fails because minlength is < 2.  So that triggers replacing the value of the element with your error message.

You may prefer to set the top level option `onkeyup:false` for jQuery Validate, but it won't completely fix the problem.

See it working differently here: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/3RBRp/8/

Answer (score 0):

Why Not use [placeholders](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp)?

They should serve your purpose quite nicely

Comment: Thanks Prat, I purposely wanted the error message to show up at input fields.  I am just trying to make them disappear when user actually type in the data where it is required.

Comment: Perhaps, I didn't make myself clear...  Thanks for the suggesting anyways!